# Image animation like flipboard automatically

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I tried [jquery flip plugin](http://amegan.github.io/jquery-flip/) . I'm able to do flipping on mouse click .

My code is

```
$("#flipRoot").flip({
        effect:"flip",
        forwardDir: "ttob",
        height: "300px",
        showpager: true,
        loop: true});
```

I tried to call same at particular intervals of time like:

```
window.setInterval(function() {
 $("#flipRoot").flip({
        effect:"flip",
        forwardDir: "ttob",
        height: "300px",
        showpager: true,
        loop: true});
}, 7200);
```

But automatic flip failed. Any idea how to implement this?
Here is [jquery fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/Q9CPe/)

Comment: have u put it in document.ready

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have checked demo page on github, this is code used by author:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Q9CPe/1/)

```
// a kind of autostart
 var timer = 2000;
 var autostart = function () {
     var $flipRoot = $("#flipRoot");
     var pageCount = $flipRoot.children(".flipContent").length;
     var flipObject = $.data($flipRoot[0], 'plugin_flip');
     var pageIdx = 0;

     return flip = function () {
         flipObject.flipNext();
         pageIdx++;
         if (pageIdx == pageCount) {
             pageIdx = 0;
         }

         setTimeout(flip, timer);
     }
 }

 setTimeout(autostart(), timer);
```